# javax.persistance.Entity not getting imported?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, gradle

I was trying to get my hands on spring data auditing. So I started with a simple build.gragle which I wrote below. But I was not able to get all the classes for javax.persistence.* What I mean is `@Entity` over any POJO was giving me cannot resolve symbol and there was no import available.I am not able to figure what I was missing in my gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'


jar {
    baseName = 'auditTest'
    version =  '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
group = 'com.shubham'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.1.RELEASE')
}
```

But then I copied the gradle file from [Spring's Getting Started with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/#scratch) page. And all the classes for `javax.persistance` were available.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'Audit'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

So what was I missing in my `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: Looks like the url `https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases` to the repo was missing.Due to this, the jar was not downloaded.

Comment: I have tried including that url. It did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the dependency graph of gradle (`gradlew dependencies`)

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: -> 1.4.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:1.4.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.4.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.4.3.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.5.6
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:8.5.6
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.5.RELEASE
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.5.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.5.RELEASE
|    |              +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.5.RELEASE
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.11.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA -> 3.20.0-GA
|    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    |    +--- org.jboss:jandex:2.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    |    |    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2 -> 1.4.01
|    |    \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final
|    |         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.11.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.11.Final (*)
|    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final (*)
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA -> 3.20.0-GA
|    +--- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:1.2
|    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.10.6.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.12.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.5.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.22 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.5.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.5.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.5.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.5.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.22 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.3.5.RELEASE
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.9
```

I see that `org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api` (where javax.persistence.* is situated) is not dependent on `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa`. Instead it depends on `org.hibernate:hibernate-core` and `org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager`.

So you should also compile these packages or stay with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.